# Jquery Mobile href odd behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, location-href

I have a rather weird problem with window.location.href. it works in nearly all pages except when called from a couple forms where data is being posted to a JSON API (using ajax) on the backend. few details:
- I am using JQuery Mobile multi-page template within Appery.
- the service being called by Ajax works just fine and returns the expected results.
- on click button has the following code:

```
$.post(url ,json_string,
   function (data, status) {
       var eid = data.body.event_id;
       localStorage.setItem('event_id', data.body.event_id);  
   })
  .done(function() {
        hideSpinner();
        window.location.href = "#job_confirm";
//      $(location).attr('href',"#job_confirm"); 
//      location.replace("#job_confirm");
  })
  .fail(function() {
//    alert( "error" );
  });
```

- as you can see in the above code. I tried multiple types of redirection. none of them worked.
- the weirdest about it is that it doesn't work the first time I install the application on my phone (compiled it into .apk). however if I swipe out the application (from the active app list in android) and start it again, it works fine! is there any bootstrapping I need to do to force href to work?

any tips would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why not use jQM's change method: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

Comment: thank you much for the tip. I tried this one too and it didn't work! for some reason the form seems to be stuck on the screen. I'm unable to move to any other screen not using the menu or even back button! I have to exist the app, kill it, and restart it. once I do that, everything works just fine! so this symptom only occurs the first time I install the app!